# Purpose of ValidatInput in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm new to programming especially to jquery and all,... From one of my friends project I got this `'$p.validatinputs'` function but I couldn't find any related function for that `$P` and it's almost declared in all script files in the same manner for input validation.

```
 if ($P.validateInputs('#data').length > 0) {}
```

Comment: this is a customized function, maybe from a plugin. But what is your question?

Comment: What is $P? Where is this created?

Comment: In firefox with firebug plugin installed you can press F12, then click the script tag and press control + f now you can search for $p in any javascript files and maybe find the deceleration.

Comment: Yeah I've done  it in that way..and got something lik this $P.Cookie.value and in most codes the validation is by using this '$P' Another one    ........$('#dob').change(function () { $('#dob').val($P.toDateTime($('#dob').val())); });

Comment: Is it a customizd function? If so is there a possibility for me to get a sample for an all in one  validateinput function?

Comment: I read that you need an example,
The Jquery Ui dialog demo show three little validator. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form Just click on "view source" in the page and you'll find them.